# Rails errors - Define Position or Object in which the error occured

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models. For example `Person` and `Address`.

Because I want to add or update addresses to the person within one request, the person model looks like:

```
has_many :addresses
accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
```

In the address controller is only one validation

```
validates :city, presence: true
```

When I now update the user via json api it works like a charm:

```
{
   "user": {
     "addresses_attributes": [
       {"street": "bla", "zip": "12345", "city": "blubb"},
       {"street": "blu", "zip": "98765", "city": "blebb"}
    ]
  }
}
```

Now I delete the city of the second record:

```
{
   "user": {
     "addresses_attributes": [
       {"street": "bla", "zip": "12345", "city": "blubb"},
       {"street": "blu", "zip": "98765"}
    ]
  }
}
```

and in the Users controller I can render a json response, something like:

```
render json: @user.errors
```

which gives me the correct error.

I am missing, that I don't know which of the addresses threw the error (In this example the second).

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the entire user object with its nested attributes and errors. I.e.

```
render json: @user.as_json(
    include: [{addresses: {methods: [:errors]}], 
    methods: [:errors]
)
```

The result should look like this:

```
{
   "user": {
     "errors": {...},
     "addresses_attributes": [
       {"street": "bla", "zip": "12345", "city": "blubb", "errors": {...}},
       {"street": "blu", "zip": "98765", "errors": {...}}
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `@user` that you tried to create will still contain the addresses that it tried to create with the nested attributes.

I don't know exactly how you want to render the fact that an address failed the validation but you can identify the one(s) that did fail by iterating over the `@user.addresses`.

For example, this will return all the invalid addresses:

```
@user.addresses.select { |address| !address.valid? }
```

You can still render these objects, or the json representation of them, even though they haven't been saved to the database.